# Apache ss logs file strange behavior

Tags: linux, apache

I have apache configuration with following logs options.

```
CustomLog logs/ssl_request_7_log \
  "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b %s \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\""
```

I can see them...

```
[root@webserver1 ~]# ls -l /var/log/httpd/ssl_request_7_log*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root        0 May 27 04:02 /var/log/httpd/ssl_request_7_log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 37299758 Oct  8 15:43 /var/log/httpd/ssl_request_7_log.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   139769 May 21 10:49 /var/log/httpd/ssl_request_7_log.2
```

Did you notice ssl_request_7_log file has zero size. Its appending realtime log in ssl_request_7_log.1 file but not in ssl_request_7_log. WHY????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved, Problem was log rotation.